# Hang problem during download report with big data

Tags: c#, performance, linq, model-view-controller, crystal-reports

I've hang problem in other accounts during download report,
this hang not happened when report contains medium data like 3000 record report take 10 second to download and other accounts are working at same time without any stuck on ant screen , but this problem happened with big data like 80000 record report take 1 min and 23 second to download it and during this time other accounts can't work because system become very slow with them if they try to insert any data it take long time or open any screen they take long time
I checked task manager and see memory is stable and CPU also , memory 71% and CPU not increase than 75%
I thought may the problem happening because when I open DB connection for report .. db not receive any other connection until first connection is closed ....but users can insert and retrieve data but it takes long time.
that's my code to retrieve report

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DALEngine.getConnectionString());
        cmd.CommandText = "Searchstoredname";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        SqlParameter l = new SqlParameter("@LanguageId", SqlDbType.Int); 
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 30000;
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            using (conn)
            {
                SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                ToCsv(sdr, columns, filepath, Usercolumns);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            success= false;
        }
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: Check your Stored Procedure and test it to run in your Database itself to monitor how long until it return a data and table indexes also.

Comment: it takes in range 1 min, and there are some indexes on columns that used in stored to make it faster